# Why Does Jenkins Show Builds In Modules When There Are No Maven Modules For My Project?

Tags: maven-2, jenkins

I'm having some trouble with Maven projects in my Jenkins
installation.  The issue that I'm seeing is that when I view my
projects in Jenkins, the build history only lists the most recent
build.  However, when I go into the "Modules" section, the previous
builds are listed there, even though there are no modules for my
project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins treats Maven jobs as containers for modules. In multi-module projects, this makes sense as the maven project is clearly made up of multiple modules. As far as Jenkins is concerned, even maven projects with no sub modules still contain a single module. Again, the job is just the container for the maven module defined in your project.